# Updating a D3 Chart within React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, redux

I have a D3(v3) chart within a React Component that is used within a Redux application. What is the best way to handle my D3 chart updating to reflect my Redux store change?

Right now, I have a function within the React component that calls the drawing of the chart and a function that calls the removal of the previous chart as soon as `componentWillUpdate` is called as so:

```
export default class Chart extends Component {
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
   this.removePreviousChart();
   this.drawChart(nextProps.chartData);
  }
  removePreviousChart(){
    const chart = document.getElementById('chart');
    while(chart.hasChildNodes())
      chart.removeChild(chart.lastChild);
    }
  } 
  drawChart() {
   //appends an svg to #chart html element and draws a d3 Chart
  }
  render(){
    this.drawChart();
    return(<div id='chart' />)
  }
}
```

Any alternative approaches, pseudocode, ideas, or feedback on how to improve this question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you followed seems fine to go with.

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new
>   props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to
>   perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called
>   for the initial render.
>
> Note that you cannot call this.setState() here. If you need to update
>   state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps()
>   instead.

Note

> componentWillUpdate() will not be invoked if shouldComponentUpdate()
>   returns false.

You can read more from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

If you want to `setState()` on receiving `newProps` use `componentWillReceiveProps()` which is fired for every new props.

Use your `Chart` `API` to draw everytime you have new props.

```
    export default class Chart extends Component {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       this.removePreviousChart();
       this.drawChart(nextProps.chartData);
      }
      removePreviousChart(){
        const chart = document.getElementById('chart');
        while(chart.hasChildNodes())
          chart.removeChild(chart.lastChild);
        }
      } 
      drawChart(chartData) {
        const chart = document.getElementById('chart'); //fails if DOM not rendered
       //appends an svg to #chart html element and draws a d3 Chart
       //assuming you chart function as Chart(element, data);
        if(chart && chartData){ //draw only if DOM rendered and have chartData
          new Chart(chart, chartData); //calls to draw graph
        }
      }
      render(){
        return(<div id='chart' />)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `componentWillUpdate` fire only when new props and/or state are being received? I'm not sure what the benefit of using `componentWillReceiveProps` over it is. Can you clarify?